# why is jquery ui autocomplete folder cannot be accessed

Tags: jquery-ui

Just wondering what could the problem be why I can't access jquery ui autocomplete folder in the prod side.

I've been using this widget in the dev side and it works perfectly. However, when I deployed it, I get errors saying, jquery.ui.core.js, jquery.ui.widget.js, jquery.ui.position.js, jquery.ui.all.css, and jquery.ui.autocomplete.js cannot be found: "404 Object Not Found".

This is how I reference these files:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/folder1/folder2/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/folder1/folder2/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/folder1/folder2/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/folder1/folder2/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/folder1/folder2/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
```

Using Firebug, these are the Response and Request headers respectively:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Object Not Found
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.0
Date: Thu, 14 Apr 2011 08:22:27 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 4040
Content-Type: text/html

GET /folder1/folder2/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js HTTP/1.1
Host: (hostname)
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: (referrer)
Cookie: (cookies)
```

I'm using Coldfusion MX 6.1. Are there permission or hosting issues involved? I don't have any idea here. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working, at last. What I did was I got all folders outside of jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom folder. That is, instead of /folder1/folder2/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js, I now have /folder1/folder2/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js.

I still don't get why the folder name jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom can't be found. If anyone knows why please tell me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you use "/" before your src addresses, you are actually telling that the "folder1" is located in the root folder of your web server (i.e. WWW in Apache)
So if "folder1" is simply a folder located in the same path that your code file is, you should use:

```
src="folder1/folder2/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"
```

Comment: actually that's my absolute path. folder1 is located in the root folder. So that's really weird. I even tried putting an html file under jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom and still it's not found! :(